# Create all directories up to a point?

Tags: java, file-io

I need to be able to build all directories up to and including the directory specified by my File object. For example, suppose I have something like this:

```
File file = new File( "/var/a/b/c/d/" );
```

But only `/var/` exists. I need a method that builds up to `d`, and I was wondering if there was a method in a java io library somewhere that does this already.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`mkdirs()` in `java.io.File` does the trick.

```
File file = new File("/var/a/b/c/d");

file.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 3):

`File.mkdirs()`